# Can't push docker built image to SSL artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

Having trouble to push docker to internal Artifactory (6.11.1).
We have Artifactory installed on port 443 with Docker setting Repository Path.

If I login to using artifactory.local.int, pull an image tag it and push it back it works

```
docker push artifactory.local/repo/image-name
```

but when I build an image my self or pull directly from docker hub and try to push
docker will try to connect to port 80 and timeout because Artifactory isn't listening to this port.

I also tried to tag an image with the port I get:

```
docker push artifactory.local:443/repo/image-name
error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character 'B' looking for the beginning of value: "Bad Request\r\nThis combination of host and port requires TLS.\r\n"
```

Am I missing some port or TLS configuration? why am I able to push pulled images back to artifactory but new images aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker push https://artifactory.local/repo/image-name
```

You might need to login first:

```
docker login https://artifactory.local/repo/
```

In your example the docker client tries accessing Artifactory over port 443, but using http protocol instead of https protocol.

Comment: I do login using https, but when I execute push to with [https://] I get "invalid reference format"

Comment: Can you share the full output?

Comment: this is the full output, I think :// are illegal

Answer (score 0):

Before you push any image to Artifactory, you have to tag it and for more details click on "Set Me Up button" in Artifactory and select the docker repository it will provide detailed steps.

Docker access method also matters, Artifactory uses 3 methods
1. Repository path
2. Subdomain
3. Port method

You have to perform the steps based on this method which you can setup in HTTP settings in Artifactory.

Comment: I stated that I used Repository Path and pushed according to the guide, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use HTTPS with Repository Path and without a reverse proxy for Docker - Artifactory integration. If you would like to keep using Repository Path you will need to configure HTTP, and if you want HTTPS you can use either Port method or SubDomain (SubDomain is more recommended).